# Why inheriting from a Collection<T> changes accessibility levels?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've created 3 classes, A, B and C.

- B inherits from A
- C inherits a Collection of A

However, I can't understand why when inheriting from a collection, the derived class can access **only** the protected member of the base class.

```
public class A
{
    public int MyPublic { get; set; }
    protected int MyProtected { get; set; }
    internal int MyInternal { get; set; }
    protected internal int MyProtectedInternal { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{
    B MyB { get; set; }
    B()
    {
        MyB.MyProtected++;
        MyB.MyInternal++;
        MyB.MyPublic++;
        MyB.MyProtectedInternal++;
    }
}
public class C : Collection<A>
{
    C MyC { get; set; }
    C()
    {
        MyC[0].MyProtected++; // Inaccessible due to its protection level.
        MyC[0].MyInternal++;
        MyC[0].MyPublic++;
        MyC[0].MyProtectedInternal++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `C` does not inherit from `A`.  `C` inherits from `Collection<T>`.

Comment: Is there a way to access a a protected member when I want to use this kind of architecture, when i need a subclass that **is-a** collection of a base class?

Comment: @eminem No. Protected members are visible only within the declaring type and within derived types. You're looking for something similar to `friend` from C++, which does not exist in C#. The closest similar modifier is `internal` and then both types must be in the same assembly. However, beware of coupling your classes tightly. Make the property internal, public, or rethink your architecture.

Comment: [*A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) and you are doing neither.

Comment: You have to forget the generic type parameter. This parameter only describes the return type of a function. Sometimes the parameter type of a function. But you are not using a function of the Collection class. This is why it is not accessible

Comment: @cdhowie So what can I do when I want a member to be accessible only in derived class, when that class **is-a** collection of it's base?

Comment: @eminem `C` _is not_ a derived class of `A`. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910). Tell us what you're trying to accomplish by doing this.

Comment: @cdhowie I need class C to be in an **is-a** relation with class A, however it is a collection of A. Therefore I inherited a collection<A>. In addiction I want MyProtected to be accessible only in its derived classes.

Comment: @eminem What you ask is not possible because you're asking for two conflicting things: in C# you can only inherit _one_ class so you cannot inherit both `C` and `Collection<C>`. You must pick one. If you state what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps there is an alternative solution. (You've only restated the Y part of XY -- what are you trying to accomplish with this pattern?)

Comment: @cdhowie I'm not sure what more can I add to my goal. In my real code, A represents a single paragraph, while C represents, well, a collection of paragraphs. A has a "content" member which I want to be accessible only within classes that are paragraph. Hope you can understand what I'm trying to do, sorry for the XY problem here :)

Comment: You should not inherit from collections in the first place.

Comment: @eminem Well there you go, you said it yourself. C is a collection of paragraphs. _C is not a paragraph itself._ Therefore is not a subtype and has no business reading that protected member.

Comment: @cdhowie I know that C is **not-a** paragraph, that is why I inherited a collection of A, and not A alone. How would you define a collection of paragraph? Remember that C does not **has-a** collection of paragraph, but **is-a**.

Comment: @eminem Correct, C _is-a_ collection of paragraphs, but C _is-not-a_ paragraph. This is why it cannot access the protected member. Only paragraphs can access that protected member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, and probably not strictly relevant to your question, I'm not sure why `C` has a member `MyC`. Type `C` *is* a `Collection<A>` so you can just use the indexer `this[int x]` to access the collection items.

To give `C` access to ALL of the members of `A` while still limiting access for anything else, you could make `C` a nested type.

```
public class A
{
    protected int MyProtected { get; set; }
    private int MyPrivate { get; set; }

    public class C : Collection<A>
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            this[0].MyProtected++; // Allowed
            this[0].MyPrivate++; // Also allowed!
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this gives `C` more access to `A` than you intended (all member regardless of access modifier).

Some discussion of pros/cons of nested classes here: [What are reasons why one would want to use nested classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300051/what-are-reasons-why-one-would-want-to-use-nested-classes)

Comment: This seems like a possible solution :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you aren't actually inheriting from `A`. You're inheriting from `Collection<T>`.

If your goal is to expose the `protected` properties of `A`, then make a class that inherits from `A` and make `public` properties of the same name that just modify the properties of the inherited class. Then make a collection of that new class.

Something like this. Notice the new class `D`:

```
public class D : A {
    new public int MyProtected {
        get {return base.MyProtected;}
        set { base.MyProtected = value; }
    }
    new public int MyProtectedInternal {
        get { return base.MyProtectedInternal; }
        set { base.MyProtectedInternal = value; }
    }
}
public class C : Collection<D>
{
    C MyC { get; set; }
    C()
    {
        MyC[0].MyProtected++;
        MyC[0].MyInternal++;
        MyC[0].MyPublic++;
        MyC[0].MyProtectedInternal++;
    }
}
```

The [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) modifier keyword indicates that you are replacing the property from the inherited type.

Comment: Wouldnt that expose MyProtected (for it being public now) to classes that are not derived from D? Remember I need MyProtected to be accessible only to derived classes.

Comment: But you also seem to want it to be accessed in a `Collection`, which means it can't be `protected`. You will need to choose which is more important to you.